# How to clear all the content of a file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

This question may sound stupid. But I do search online and couldn't find a answer. So what's the emacs command to clear all the content in a file? I want to clear my error_log file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than `erase-buffer`, you can use `C-x h C-w`.

Comment: Note that `C-x h C-w` selects the whole buffer and kills the selection, so the whole buffer will be put in the kill ring. Depending on how big your buffer is (you may be for example following a very large log file) this may be undesirable.

Comment: @PedroRomano: indeed, if the buffer is large it can make a significant difference in terms of memory use, but note that `erase-buffer` also stashes the whole buffer's content somewhere for later use (the undo-log), so in most cases the difference is negligible.

Comment: So just do `C-d` instead of `C-w`.  Or backspace, if you're using delete-selection-mode.

Answer (score 4):

Is `M-x erase-buffer` what you are looking for? Note that it is disabled by default because new users find it confusing and you'll be asked about enabling it temporarily or permanently the first time you run it. You can then bind it to a keyboard shortcut for convenience.